# Ajax live search add timer after first key pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, search

I got an ajax live search script which searches names in a database. My problem is that I use `keyup();` so every time a key is pressed inside the input field the php script is fired again. This results in the output being refreshed multiple times (depending on how many characters the searched word has).

So I added a timer of 300 milliseconds but this is too slow when starting to type. My solution was immediatly fire the php script on the first key pressed, and after the first key add the timer. This way the user sees something is happening right away.

How can I achieve this with my current code? Or is there a better solution than what I have in mind?

My code:

```
<input type="search" name="keyword" class="producten-icon divider" placeholder="Zoeken..." id="s_search">
```

My ajax:

```
<script>
    var typingTimer;
    var doneTypingInterval = 300;

    $("#s_search").on('keyup',function () {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer)
        var key = $(this).val();
        if(key == ""){
          $(".defaultresults").css("display", "inline");
          $(".phpresult").css("display", "none");
        }else{
          typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
          $(".defaultresults").css("display", "none");

        }

        function doneTyping () {
          $.ajax({
              url:'includes/fetch_results.php',
              type:'GET',
              data:'keyword='+key,
              beforeSend:function () {
                  $("#results").slideUp('fast');
              },
              success:function (data) {
                  $("#results").html(data);
                  $("#results").slideDown('fast');
              }
          });
        }


    });
</script>
```

And finally my php file:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$conn = new Connection;
if($_GET['keyword'] && !empty($_GET['keyword']))
{
  //  Results names
  $results                  = "SELECT `naam` FROM `producten` WHERE `naam` LIKE '".$_GET['keyword']."%'";
  $resultscon               = $conn->query($results);
  $resultscr                = array();
  while ($resultscr[] = $resultscon->fetch_assoc());
  $eend = @array_map('current', $resultscr);
  sort($eend, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
  // echo '<pre>';
  // print_r($eend);
  // echo '</pre>';
  echo '<div class="phpresult"><ul class="productenlijst">';
  foreach($eend as $key => $result){
    //De eerste waarde is leeg dus voor de code pas uit als key nummer is niet 0
    if($key != '0'){
      echo '<li>';
      $char = $result[0];
      if($char !== $lastChar){
        if($lastChar !== ''){
          echo '<br>';
        }
        echo '<span style="color:#eb9600;font-size:25px;font-weight:800;">'.strtoupper($char).'</span><br>';
        $lastChar = $char;
      }
      echo $result.'<br></li>';
      $i++;
    }
  }
  echo '</ul></div>';
};
?>
```

Comment: I use [Debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#debounce) for this kind of problems.

Comment: What the size of the producten table? Your problem may be the query. If was this, make a size validation of your #s_search.

Comment: Or call doneTyping in ajaxStop event. When the request have completed. https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: Can you describe exactly what your desired behaviour is either as requests per interval or requests per typed characters or a combination of the two

Comment: Also worth a look is twitter typeahead https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ - It supports local caching of the data which is particularly useful for datasets  in the 100s

Answer (score 0):

How about setting an interval and that resets a boolean checking if you can send it

```
var sendSearch = true;
var isTiming = false;
var timeout = 300;

$("#s_search").on("keyup", function(){

if (!isTiming){
    isTiming = true;
    setInterval(function(){sendSearch = true;}, timeout);
}

if (sendSearch){

    sendSearch = false;     
    // do your ajax post here   
}

});
```

Comment: This has the same result as my code only difference I noticed was the query did not fire again when I used backspace to shorten the search word